# Opening SQLite 3 shell, but initialized with dot commands

Tags: bash, sqlite, shell

Due to an interactive learning application I'm building, I need to initialize the SQLite shell with various dot commands, but initiating with dot commands does not seem to work like passing a SQL string.

For example, I cannot open a SQLite database, but instruct it to set the widths of the first six columns:

```sh
./sqlite3 -column -header rexon_metals.db ".width 25 25 25 25 25 25"
```

It just seems to exit the SQLite shell abruptly. How I can initialize with dot commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in commands to run with `-cmd`.

```
./sqlite3 -column -header -cmd '.width 25 25 25 25 25 25' rexon_metals.db
```

Alternatively, `-init` will read commands from a file. This is safer, and it avoids shell escaping problems.

```
./sqlite3 -init some_temp_file.sqlite
```

See the [SQLite 3 man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sqlite3) for more.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
./sqlite3 '.mode -column' '-header on' rexon_metals.db '.width 25 25 25 25 25 25'
```

The complete command I do:

```
sqlite3 mydata.db '.mode on' '.header on' '.width 25 25 25 25 25 25' 'select foo,bar,baz,more,qux,lux from mytable DESC limit 20;'
```

I always use a function:

```
myfunction() {
  sqlite3 rexon_metals.db "$@"
}
```

Then I can run:

```
myfunction '.mode -column' '-header on' '.width 25 25 25 25 25 25'
```

Comment: I'd mark this as the answer but it does not go into SQLite's shell for interactivity mode. Thanks for these tips though, still useful.